# Convert php code to string, opposite to eval()

Tags: php

**How can I convert callable (anonymous function) into a string for eval?**

I'm trying to write unit tests in phpunit that use [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php) to override methods. And in particular, `runkit_method_redefine()` requires a string parameter that will be `eval()`-called later.

I want to have syntax highlighting of my test code, so I don't want to write code inside of a string, so I want to do something like

```php
deEval(function(){ 
   return 1;
});
```

that would output

```php
"return 1;"
```

How can this be done easily (for example without doing fopen of the source file, finding a source line, parsing etc.)?

Comment: Hm I think you have to write your PHP code as string cause every statement you write as such one gets interpreted by PHP. So you hvae no chance to fetch it and use it as "plain code".

Comment: @User016 it's not _deprecated_ It's _evil_

Comment: @AlmaDo using runkit is also considered a dark side of unit-testing, I know

Comment: Why don't use combinaison of eval and call_user_func()  ? eval("call_user_func('yourfunction)")

Comment: or just append a pair of parentheses to the function name?

Comment: I don't have a PHP instance with runkit installed to test this, but I *think* http://3v4l.org/EQd35 will work. Note that I am emphatically **not** *recommending* it, but I think it will work for your specific use case (note that it will not work if you just eval() it)

Comment: @DaveRandom add it as an answer please

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov Working on a better version, doesn't play as nice as I'd like with arguments at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***NOTE**: I do not like this solution and I would not recommend it to anyone for anything, but it does solve the problem set out in the question.*

---

```
class CallableStringifier
{
    private static $callables = array();

    public static function stringify($callable)
    {
        $id = count(self::$callables);
        self::$callables[$id] = $callable;
        return 'return ' . __CLASS__ . "::call($id, func_get_args());";
    }

    public static function call($id, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(self::$callables[$id], $args);
    }
}
```

This will work for your specific use case (which is essentially `create_function()`). It will *not* work if you just `eval()` it, because it relies on being inside a function context.

Example:

```
$func = create_function('$arg1', CallableStringifier::stringify(function($arg1) {
    return $arg1;
}));

echo $func(1); // outputs 1
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/ivMri)

Comment: Thanks. Although people should keep in mind that this doesn't really generate a true method body text, because it depends on current php process and whatever is stored in CallableStringifier::$callables.

So if someone wants to write generated code in DB to be executed later, its not a good idea (not to mention its not a good idea to do it at all).

But for current automated testing purposes its more efficient than reading file source

Comment: Addendum: following on from the previous comment, if your *are* trying to "write generated code in DB to be executed later", you need to take a long, hard look at your application design ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a not-so efficient function.. (doesn't take into account arguments)

```
/**
 * Converts method code to string by reading source code file
 * Function brackets {} syntax needs to start and end separately from function body
 *
 * @param Callable $callable method to deevaluate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function callableToString($callable) {
    $refFunc = new ReflectionFunction($callable);
    $startLine = $refFunc->getStartLine();
    $endLine   = $refFunc->getEndLine();

    $f      = fopen($refFunc->getFileName(), 'r');
    $lineNo = 0;

    $methodBody = '';
    while($line = fgets($f)) {
        $lineNo++;
        if($lineNo > $startLine) {
            $methodBody .= $line;
        }
        if($lineNo == $endLine - 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($f);

    return $methodBody;
}
```